# moding a hozelock water valve with raspi

Tags: gpio

I am new to electronics and could use some pointers from you good people. I am wanting to modfiy a hozelock AC1 water control valve (i have one hanging around) so i can control the valve using a raspberry pi rather than use the restrictive inbuilt program options. i have opened the valve up (see pic)

[image: hozelock AC1]

From proding around with a multimeter it looks like the motor is 3V which drives various cogs to open or close the valve. The motor turns when 1.25V reads from the yellow wire which i think is connected to a simple switch so the motor only turns the valve through 90 degrees. After the voltage drops to zero on the yellow wire and stops the motor (i hope that makes sense).

My question is, what hardware would i need to be able to connect the valve to the raspi (i dont think i should run it direct from the GPIO pins)? Also, could anyone recommend a simple circuit.

Many thanks
Alex